# Python Tornado - Message all clients

Tags: python, websocket, raspberry-pi, tornado

I'm using Tornado as a websocket server on a Raspberry Pi that takes incoming messages, parses them and then will sometime broadcast a message back to all clients. This all works fine but I'd like the ability to broadcast a message to all clients when the user presses a button using RPi.GPIO. This is the code I have at the moment:

```
# Define websockets server
define('port', default=8080)

# Global websocket connections
ws_connections = []

# Called from RPi.GPIO Button event detection
def handle_button(pin):
   if pin == 10:
       broadcast_msg = {"request": "broadcast", "data": "test_message"}
       game_controller_broadcast(broadcast_msg)

# Websockets handler
class game_websockets_handler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
   
   # Called when new connection opened
   def open(self):
       ws_connections.append(self)

   # Called when a message is received
   def on_message(self, message):
       print("Message received: {}".format(message))
       json_data = json.loads(message)
       self.write_message(json.dumps(game_controller_parse_request(json_data)))
   
   # Called when a connection closes
   def on_close(self):
       ws_connections.remove(self)

   # Accept all cross-origin traffic
   def check_origin(self, origin):
       return True

   @classmethod
   def route_urls(cls):
       return [(r'/',cls, {}),]

def game_websockets_init():
   #create a tornado application and provide the urls
   app = tornado.web.Application(game_websockets_handler.route_urls())

   #setup the server
   server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
   server.listen(options.port)
   
   #start io/event loop
   tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()

def game_controller_broadcast(json_message):
   [client.write_message(json.dumps(json_message)) for client in ws_connections]
```

If I call `game_controller_broadcast()` from within `game_controller_parse_request()` it works just fine. But when I call it from within `handle_button()` I get the error:

> RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Dummy-1'.

What am I missing here? How can I broadcast messages from outside of Tornado?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like whatever calls `handle_button()` does so on a separate thread. The only thread-safe method in Tornado is `IOLoop.add_callback`, so you need to do this to transfer control to the IOLoop thread:

```
def handle_button(pin):
    if pin == 10:
        broadcast_msg = {"request": "broadcast", "data": "test_message"}
        main_io_loop.add_callback(lambda:
            game_controller_broadcast(broadcast_msg))
```

You must save `main_io_loop` in a global variable from the main thread before starting either the IOLoop or the thread that goes on to call handle_button.